# onscreenclick not working in turtle, python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to make a button be pressed on a screen using turtle python. It's not difficult, but I tried to do it using a class and it didn't work:

```
class Window:
    def __init__(self):
         self.name = 'test'

    def deletewindow(self, x, y):
         if x < 10 and x > 0 and y < 10 and y > 0:
             del self

wn.listen()
wn.onscreenclick(deletewindow, 1)
```

And this is the error  I'm getting:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
      return self.func(*args)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 675, in eventfun
      fun(x, y)
TypeError: deletewindow() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `deletewindow` function requires a parameter called self, which usually would be given but you put `deletewindow` not `Window.deletewindow`.

You should do

```
wn.onscreenclick(Window.deletewindow, 1)
```

Comment: I did that, but the problem still is there.

Comment: Oh, sorry, don't do Window.deletewindow, if you have an object that is a Window class, use that. For example, say you did window = Window(), do ```wn.onscreenclick(window.deletewindow, 1)```.